# Apache SSL Certificate Installation on Windows server

Tags: windows, apache, ssl, server, pem

Wanted to get advice for how can I install Apache SSL Certificate on Windows 2016 Server.

I ordered SSL and now received .crt and .p7c and .pem and one more .crt file.
Also, I have read an article about SSL certificate installation.

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html2
ServerName www.yourdomain.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/your_domain_name.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/your_private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/CA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Here, I think it needs the files with .crt, .key and ChainFile with .crt extensions.
But now, I have only domain_name.crt file and others are perm, p7c and  server.crt file.

It will be appreciated if someone gives me advice with these problems.
Thank you